# mongoose: when timestamps: true auto deletes document after 1 minute?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, timestamp

With the following scheme below, documents get deleted after approx 1 minute. The intention is to have the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields for each document.

```
let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 50,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 255,
        unique: true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 1024,
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```